# SQL Parent/Child CTE Ordering

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I'm trying to create a forum setup where you can comment on specific posts and have the replies show immediately below the parent in date order.  There will only be one sub-level below the parent.  Here's the example dataset:

```
ID.ParentID.Datestamp
12.NULL.2013-03-01 1:00pm
13.NULL.2013-03-01 2:00pm
14.12.2013-03-01 2:20pm
15.12.2013-03-01 2:30pm
16.NULL.2013-03-01 3:30pm
```

And here's what I'm trying to end up with:

```
12.NULL.2013-03-01 1:00pm
14.12.2013-03-01 2:20pm
15.12.2013-03-01 2:30pm
13.NULL.2013-03-01 2:00pm
16.NULL.2013-03-01 3:30pm
```

I know I need some sort of CTE going, but this doesn't order the children under the appropriate parent (obviously, since there's no ORDER BY clause); I couldn't figure out the proper ordering.  Can anyone provide some insight?

```
; WITH Messages
AS 
(
    SELECT ID, ParentID, Datestamp
    FROM ForumMessages
    WHERE ParentID IS NULL

    -- Recursive
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT
        t2.ID, t2.ParentID, t2.Datestamp
    FROM
        ForumMessages AS t2
        JOIN Messages AS m ON t2.ParentID = m.ID
)

SELECT ID, ParentID, Datestamp
FROM Messages
```

Comment: Your final statement is a simple select from the CTE-generated set. It has no ORDER BY clause.

Comment: True.  I had tried a few things, but couldn't figure out the proper ordering.  Do you have an answer?

Comment: Also, in a real-world application such as you describe (forum) you would not sort everything in the database; rather you would wait until the user clicked on a particular forum message and only then woud you retrieve its related sub-postings, which you could sort by datetime-posted.

Comment: Furthermore, the subpostings could have sub-sub-postings. The subposting with sub-sub-postings would have a parent-id and they would not be included by a query that looked for ParentId is null.

Comment: As I said, `In a real-world application such as you describe`.  Your forum would have to have very few postings for it to perform well, if you're selecting everything all the time, rather than on-demand.

Comment: There will only be one sub-level, edited to show this.

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices2005/billofmaterials/

Comment: My last post was before you said there would be only a single level depth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a single level depth, you don't need to use recursion - try:

```
SELECT ID, ParentID, Datestamp
FROM ForumMessages
order by coalesce(ParentID,ID), Datestamp
```

Comment: Mark, you answered first.  Thanks for saving me from over-engineering!

Answer (score 0):

Very easy way without CTE (ISNULL is the function in MSSQL but you don't give the RDBMS):

```
SELECT ID, ParentID, Datestamp

FROM ForumMessages

ORDER BY ISNULL(ParentID,ID), DateStamp
```

**[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/24b51/1/0)**