# SQL Server Parent/Child CTE Ordering issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to create a query that returns a record set of parent notes, with their child notes listed beneath each parent, ordered by the parent (root) note id.

For example, here is the output I would like to see:

[image]

I used the accepted solution from [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271308/sql-parent-child-cte-ordering), which was this:

```
SELECT ID, ParentID, Datestamp
FROM ForumMessages
ORDER BY coalesce(ParentID, ID), Datestamp
```

My resultant query was:

```
SELECT NoteID, ParentNoteID, NoteText
FROM dms_Notes
WHERE DocketID = 43477 -- this filter is just to make the resultset smaller
ORDER BY Coalesce(NoteID, ParentNoteID), NoteText
```

Which resulted in the output below. As you can see, the last record with id 23478 is not listed below the parent 23471

[image]

I also tried switching the `ORDER BY` around to `ParentNoteID, NoteID`, but the result was even further off:

[image]

What is wrong and why is this not working? I have tried to base it exactly on the accepted solution, but it just doesn't appear to work properly? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try:

```
SELECT NoteID, ParentNoteID, NoteText
FROM dms_Notes
WHERE DocketID = 43477 -- this filter is just to make the resultset smaller
ORDER BY IIF(ParentNoteID <> 0, ParentNoteID, NoteID), NoteText
```

The [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) functions returns the first element that `IS NOT NULL`, but you are using `0` instead `NULL` to check if element is parent.

In the providing StackOverflow link, the user is using `NULL' to do this. Because of this you have to change the condition logic user in the`ORDER BY` clause.

EDIT:

As `marc_S` point in his comment, if you are not using SQL Server 2012, you can replace the IIF statement with `CASE WHEN` block.

Comment: `IIF` is a **new feature** in SQL Server **2012** - it's not available in earlier versions

Comment: @gotqn I should have seen that. Well spotted and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have the same setup as the referenced post. Specifically, you have 0 for a parentid when it doesn't have a parent instead of NULL. So, the COALESCE will never do anything. So, you need something like:

```
Order by case when parentid = 0 then noteid else parentid end
```