# SQL Server Parent/Child CTE Ordering issue revisited

Tags: sql, sql-server

Yesterday, I posted [this issue regarding Parent/Child ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20160948/sql-server-parent-child-cte-ordering-issue) that I thought had been resolved.

The resultant query that worked for a while was:

```
SELECT NoteID, ParentNoteID, NoteText
FROM dms_Notes
WHERE DocketID = 43477
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ParentNoteID = 0 THEN NoteID ELSE ParentNoteID END
```

As you can see in the output below, it worked well. But then later on it went awry after adding more children records after NoteID 23480.

[image]

As you can see, the children after that, that have a ParentNoteID of 23482 don't seem to be listed under the relevant parent Note, bu rather at the end.

Why is this? Thanks

UPDATE: Here is another simpler example. As you can see, the child for the second parent (23499) doesn't sit under the parent. So is it correct to say that the previous solution provided doesn't actually work properly?

[image]

Comment: Why? It's because the parentid of 23482 isn't 0. This will only work for a tree with a depth of 2.

Comment: @Ben: I was under the impression that it would list all children (including their children) under the parent? How would I accomplish that? Thanks

Comment: What SQL Server version ?

Comment: It cannot order any differently than what your order by dictates.
And 23482 will come after 23480. The "error" is your order by does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Also, what's the maximum depth of the tree?  We can attempt to 'cheat' for another level, or if the answer is 'infinite', we need to use something else (probably recursive CTE)

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen: Updated the example. Even at only one level the children do not place under their parents correctly.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: But even for one level it isnt working - see updated question.

Comment: @Ben: See updated question with one level exhibiting the issue. Thanks

Comment: They're still ordered by your order by. It's not the query that is wrong, it's that the order by does not do what you want it to, but that does not make it wrong. You Order by NoteID when ParentNote is 0 and because there's no difference between 23499 and 23499 you cannot be guaranteed an order. The order by works. In your previous example, 23480 < 23482 and therefore that order is also correct

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen: So I guess I need to post a new question about how to accomplish what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is use a `Revursive CTE` to find the `RootId` which you can then use in the `ORDER BY`

```
;WITH c AS 
(
    SELECT NoteId, NoteId ParentNoteId, NoteId AS RootId, t.NoteText
    FROM tbl 
    WHERE ParentNoteId = 0 

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT t.NoteId, t.ParentNoteId, c.RootId, t.NoteText
    FROM tbl AS t 
    INNER JOIN c ON t.ParentNoteId = c.NoteId 
    WHERE t.NoteId <> 0
) 
SELECT 
    c.NoteId, 
    CASE WHEN c.ParentNoteId = c.NoteId THEN 0 ELSE c.ParentNoteId END AS ParentId, 
    c.NoteText
FROM c
ORDER BY RootId, ParentNoteId, NoteId
```

Which give a result like (text ommitted)

```
NoteId  ParentId
--------------------
23471   0
23472   23471
23473   23471
23478   23471
23481   23471
23474   23472
23475   23474
23476   0
23477   23476
23482   23476
23484   23482
23485   23482
23486   23482
23487   23482
23480   0
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/12174)