# SQL Server, why does one order by query work with a string, but not with an integer?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is a simple example of one level deep ordering by parent/child without using CTE. Got the example from here: [SQL Parent/Child CTE Ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271308/sql-parent-child-cte-ordering)

I re-created this fiddle and there's something I'm not understanding.

Take a look at this fiddle and you'll see that it's ordering the children beneath the parent properly:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/53851/4

I'd like to use this as an example to share with someone and keep from having to use a CTE.

Does anyone know how to make something as simple as this work and still obey sortorder for parent and child? So that parent's are in order, and children beneath those parents are in order according to their own sortorder?

-------- Example of desired results ----------

If the table consists of:

```
ID | ParentID | SortOrder
-------------------------
1  | NULL     | 1
2  | NULL     | 2
3  | NULL     | 3
4  | 1        | 1
5  | 1        | 2
6  | 3        | 1
```

I'd like the query to return:

```
ID | ParentID | SortOrder
-------------------------
1  | NULL     | 1
4  | 1        | 1
5  | 1        | 2
2  | NULL     | 2
3  | NULL     | 3
6  | 3        | 1
```

Comment: Order by ParentSortOrder, SortOrder.   Obviously ParentSortOrder isn't a column, but can be generated in your query.

Comment: What do you mean "causes it to fail"?   I'm not seeing any error.

Comment: Could you provide an example showing what you expect the properly sorted result to look like?

Comment: @Dan just added an example - edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to know the SortOrder of the Parent, when at the Child Level, you need a subquery in your `ORDER BY`-clause as suggested elsewhere, or alternatively do a self-join like this (to find the parent record from which you need the firstmost SortOrder):

```
SELECT C.Id, C.ParentId, C.SortOrder
FROM Table1 AS C
LEFT JOIN Table1 AS P ON P.Id = C.ParentId
ORDER BY 
    -- This ensures that records are sorted correctly at the parent level:
    COALESCE(P.SortOrder, C.SortOrder), 
    -- This sorts the records at the child level. We need the CASE to make sure parents are sorted before children:
    CASE WHEN C.ParentId IS NULL THEN -1 ELSE C.SortOrder END
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/53851/18)

Comment: The other question where you just commented was removed but was going to say that it worked... or seemed to but haven't tested thoroughly yet, and was trying your suggestion now. I've always used a traditional CTE to handle this and think I may have over-complicated things.

Comment: So I'd create dynamic columns for first and second order, select with outer query, and order by based on the two levels.

Comment: I've edited my answer with some more details and a SQL fiddle link. Note that the answer assumes, that you do not have any records where the SortOrder is less than 0.

Comment: Correct. 0 is the lowest. Trying now.

Comment: fantastic answer. So much better for 1 level deep models. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with integer vs. string.   Your fiddle has this in the ORDER BY:

```
order by coalesce(ParentID,ID)
```

What that says is, if there's a ParentID, order by that, and ignore ID.  If there's no ParentID, order by ID.   But every row will be ordered by a single value, so Parents and Children will all be treated the same.

What you WANT is to order by ParentID, ID, and NOT by the ID's but by their SortOrders.   That way the children are in their own order under their Parent.

So in pseudo-code:

```
ORDER BY 
  <sub-query or artificial column that contains SortOrder for Parents and the Parent's SortOrder for children>, 
  <sub-query or artificial column that contains zero for parents and SortOrder for children>
```